# Print Type Parameter's Type

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> def f[A]: Unit = ???
f: [A]=> Unit
```

I'd like to replace the definition to print out `A`'s type.

Is there any alternative to:

```
scala> def f[A](implicit manifest: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) = manifest.toString
f: [A](implicit manifest: scala.reflect.Manifest[A])String

scala> f[String]
res10: String = java.lang.String
```

Comment: Why you need an alternative? The implementation you provided does what you require

Comment: I'm just curious if I can avoid the `manifest` - if there's a more concise way to do it

Comment: You would need a macro to do that without manifests. It would be a nice exercise if you want to learn, but it will certainly not result in something more concise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That isn't actually printing out the type, it's printing out the class.

```
scala> f[List[Int]]
res17: String = scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
```

Use a `TypeTag` to get the *type* information. But no, there isn't a simpler way. Since this is happening at runtime, you need the `TypeTag` to hold the type information.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

scala> def f[A](implicit tt: TypeTag[A]): Unit = println(typeOf[A])
f: [A](implicit tt: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])Unit

scala> f[List[Int]]
scala.List[Int]
```

We can make it *look* more concise with the context bound syntax:

```
def f[A : TypeTag]: Unit = println(typeOf[A])
```